# How to call method defined in Default.aspx.cs from another class

Tags: c#, asp.net, default, class-method

I am fairly new to asp.net and I am trying to create website. I have a class in AppCode/GSA in which I need to access event handler declared in default.aspx.cs. Can anyone help with it? 
I tried searching about it but all I got is standard method calls like classname.methodname() after creating an instance of that class. Please help me out here.

here is what I want to do and the reason why I need to call the method in default.aspx.cs

I am calling GSA functions to make html string which I am using to display search results in place holder. It works perfectly fine. Now I am adding button in front of every search displayed. When user clicks this button that button should be replaced by textfield and it will contain tiny url for that search result.

Now I am getting button with every result displayed, I have to assign event handler to that button. I tried putting that event handler in GSA.cs file itself but that function does not get called as it is not defined in default that why i decided to put that event handler in defalut.aspx.cs

Comment: Why? You should probably move the code in the handler to a separate class.

Comment: You shouldn't be accessing an event handler from within class in App_Code, and you shouldn't need to either. Find a way to feed the information into the class from the event handler, or take the code in the event handler and put it somewhere more accessible. If you can post some code, we'll try to help you with that.

Comment: I have edited the problem to elaborate more about the problem I am facing.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, event handlers aren't the sort of thing that should be shared between classes.  If you need to use the same functionality in two places, then pull that functionality out into its own method and invoke that method in your event handlers:

```
private void MyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // some complex functionality
}
```

Should become:

```
public void DoComplexFunctionality()
{
    // some complex functionality
}

private void MyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoComplexFunctionality();
}
```

The question of "where do I put `DoComplexFunctionality()`?" is one that can only be meaningfully answered by someone who knows the specifics of what it does.  You could make it a member of a static class, which would make it accessible to any code that can see that class.  Or, if it's responsible for mutating a specific set of values, you could make it an instance member of a class that encapsulates those values, and pass an instance of that class to whoever needs to invoke the method.

In any case, trying to directly call an event handler is not the way to go.

Comment: I edited my questions to explain why I am taking this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You really should simply never be calling an event handler from other code.

I don't really have enough information to go on but I can envision two scenarios that might be giving you the idea that you should do this: a common page scenario and a shared business logic scenario.

If you are hoping to use some block of code in multiple pages, then I would strongly recommend that you create a parent class derived from the "Page" class and place all common code in there.  This is NOT the same as a master-slave relationship; it is simply a way to implement code that all of your pages will use.  I use my parent class to manage a strongly-typed session class, for example.

If you are looking to share or implement business logic and it just happens that you already put it in the Default.aspx.cs class, then you need to rethink your architecture.  Even if you are not using an MVC approach, I would strongly recommend that you approach all but the most trivial of sites with a three-tier approach (once you've done it, additional work is trivial).  In this case, you'll create classes that implement your business logic and only use your code-behind code for UI work.  So your typical code-behind method will pull some stuff from the UI, create a business logic class and pass it in, and then process the results (or vice versa).  In this case, you'll be able to call the business logic class that implements the code you want to share from anywhere - including your testing classes.

Answer (score 1):

Drag your *Default.aspx.cs* to the *AppCode* folder with all your other classes and change the `CodeFile` path in your *Default.aspx* to `CodeFile="~/App_Code/Default.aspx.cs"` 
You should now be able to access it like any other class.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

Default.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string a = Class1.ctest();
        Response.Write(a);
    }
}
```

In App_Code/Class1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Class1
/// </summary>
public class Class1
{
    public Class1()
    {

    }
    public static string ctest()
    {
        string test = "I need this";
        return test;
    }
}
```

Updated (code requested by the OP):
Default.aspx.cs:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
    { 
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
    string a = pick();
    Response.Write(a);
    }
    protected string pick() 
    { 
    string test = "I need this";
    return test;
    }
    }
```

Comment: @Mark - How can I code for him without knowing what he exactly mean. As far as his question says is "He needs how to use a calling function" for that I wrote a sample code. I hope! he can develop what he need by taking the reference of my code.

Comment: no I want to do exact opposite of it.. I want to use event handler describe in default.aspx.cs in another class

Comment: I don't think its possible using calling functions. But if you wanna pass little data you can better make use of `Sessions`. Or if you just need to use call function from same page try the below..

Comment: `public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string a = pick();
        Response.Write(a);
    }
    protected string pick()
 {
        string test = "I need this";
        return test;
 }
}`

Comment: oh ok.. about the above code that you gave me where should I put it in default / class from where I am calling it ?